# output of function doesn't change as inputs change

Tags: r

Does anyone know why the output never changes?

```
response <- function(sw, r, delta) {
  exp(0.05795)*exp((1.60217662E-19^2)/8*pi*298*1.381E-23*8.854E-12*(1/sw*((1/r)-(1/(r+delta+0.008399)))-1/2.2*(1/r-1/(r+delta))))-1
}

value<-response(1,1,1)
formatted_value <- format(value, nsmall = 20)
print(formatted_value)

"0.05966201128512360619"

value<-response(2,2,2)
formatted_value <- format(value, nsmall = 20)
print(formatted_value)

"0.05966201128512360619"
```

No matter how I change the inputs, the output is always "0.05966201128512360619". This is not consistent with the results in Excel.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You have at least  `3e-70` on the exponent. You need a number as small as such to detect the changes:

```
response(1, 1e-70, 1)
[1] 6.857331
response(1e-70, 1, 1)
[1] 5.700413
```

This is because at one point you have

```
1.60217662E-19^2/8*pi*298*1.381E-23*8.854E-12
[1] 3.673078e-70
```

You need to counter that factor.